# Conditional Sum to a Specific Total in a Single Column

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to weighted average of available stock ie 888 Items. We operate FIFO so that means I need to start sum from recent date backwards. How do i only select those cells that sum up to available stock balance (888) then sumproduct with the price?

```
Date    Items Recieved  Price
9/1/2022    254 $25.00
8/25/2022   242 $25.00
8/18/2022   230 $65.00
8/11/2022   218 $77.00
8/4/2022    206 $45.00
7/28/2022   194 $77.00
7/21/2022   182 $89.00
7/14/2022   737 $74.00
7/7/2022    1292    $86.00
6/30/2022   1847    $87.00
```

Query, Arrayformula & SUMproduct

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You tagged both Excel and Google sheets. They're different. In Excel (Office 365) you can do this using:

```
=LET(stock,888,
     data,B2:C11,
          items,INDEX(data,,1),
          price,INDEX(data,,2),
                cumulative,SCAN(0,items,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),               
                r,XMATCH(stock,cumulative,1),            
                correction,INDEX(items,r)+stock-INDEX(cumulative,r),
SUMPRODUCT(
           IFERROR(
                   VSTACK(
                      TAKE(items,r-1),
                      correction),
                   correction),
           TAKE(price,r)))
```

`stock` is the number to sum up to.
`data` is the range containing both the items and prices.
`SCAN` is used to get the cumulative sum of all items row-by-row.
`XMATCH` is used to find the row (`r`) in the cumulative sum where the value is greater than or equal to the stock value.
`r` is used to correct the items in that row to the value required to get the cumulative sum up to row `r` equal to the stock value. (Item in row `r` + stock - cumulative sum in row `r`).
I than take the rows before `r` of the items and add (stack) the correction items value calculated and use that in a SUMPRODUCT with the prices up to `r`.
If `r` is the first row it'll throw an error at the `TAKE(items,r-1)`-part, if so IFERROR makes sure the corrected value is used without stacking it on previous items values.

Edit: since you mentioned FIFO you'd probably be interested to calculate from the bottom up. In this case you could use:

```
=LET(stock,888,
     data,SORT(A2:C11,1,1),
          items,INDEX(data,,2),
          price,INDEX(data,,3), 
          cumulative,SCAN(0,items,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
      
          r,XMATCH(stock,cumulative,1),
correction,INDEX(items,r)+stock-INDEX(cumulative,r),
SUMPRODUCT(       
           IFERROR(
                   VSTACK(
                      TAKE(items,r-1),
                      correction),
                   correction),
           TAKE(price,r)))
```

It works the same, it just uses an extra column for the data, so it could sort from old (first in) to new.

[image]

And it's unclear if you wanted this SUMPRODUCT or the average of it, but that's simply adding `/stock` to the last argument of `LET`